# Angular2: Importing Bootstrap Plugins

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, angular, plugins, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have got a Problem with Angular2, Bootstrap 3.3.7 and Bootstrap Plugins.
In the 'index.html' I imported all the stylesheets and JavaScript-Files.

Here´s the `index.html`:

```
<!-- Bootstrap & JQuery -->
<script src="js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/tether.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- Bootstrap Toggle Switch -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-toggle.min.css">
<script src="js/bootstrap-toggle.min.js"></script>

<!-- Bootstrap Table -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-table.min.css">
<script src="js/bootstrap-table.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap-table-zh-CN.min.js"></script>

<!-- eigener Stylesheet -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/custom.css">

<script>
      System.import('app').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
</script>
<base href="/">
</head>
<!-- 4. Display the application -->
<body>
    <DVBViewerApp>Loading...</DVBViewerApp>
</body>
</html>
```

The Files are all found by the lite-server, but i have one problem:
Bootstrap 3.3.7 itself is working over the whole application without a problem.
But both plugins (bootstrap-toggle & bootstrap-table) are not working on any of my components. They are JUST working at the `index.html`.

Does anyone know what´s the problem?

Thank you very much!

Comment: This isn't proper way to import `bootstrap` or another css framework in Angular.You should download bootstrap files via  `npm install bootstrap`

Answer (score 0):

First run npm install bootstrap@3.3.7.

Then check if your project structure is same as mine.

project
  |____ e2e
  |____ node_modules
  |____ src
  |____ .gitignore
  |____ angular.json
  |____ package.json
  |____ package-lock.json
  |____ tsconfing.json
  |____ tslint.json

If same add [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PnFzY.png).